# Кастомизация списков

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно создать что-то наподобие этого (см.изображение)? Свой адаптер писать или как-то ещё можно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, свой адаптер с вьюхолдером

Comment: В [этой книге](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136792911/) есть хороший пример. Книга есть в свободном доступе в электронном виде. Более того, прочитав ее, Вы узнаете много чего нового.

Comment: А страницу не подскажите?

Comment: Хоть и не модный нынче ListView, но с данной задачей справится легко [Кастомизация списка. Создаем свой адаптер](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html)

Comment: используйте `RecyclerView`. `ListView` давно уже устарел.

Comment: я как-то долек от использования RecyclerView. ListView легче идет для меня или я не прав? может работать с RecyclerView действительно проще?

Answer (score 0):

RecylerView используйте, напишите свой RecyclerView.Adapter , в нём есть ViewHolder, который представляет собой абстракцию элемента списка, верстается визуальное представление элемента списка так же как и обычный layout.